# How can I share a USB drive on a wired network?

Tags: networking, windows-8, usb, windows-networking

I have

- Windows 8.1.
- An external USB hard drive connected to my PC via USB.
- A [Netgear Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV2Vb.jpg) connected via Ethernet.
- A wireless network I’m connected to (this is relevant because I’m connected to it and explicitly don’t want to share the USB device on it — only on the wired network).

What I want to do is to share the USB hard drive with everyone on my wired network — essentially making myself the ‘host’, or rather making the USB device a ‘place’ on the wired drive people can send/receive from.

I have tried sharing the USB drive, tried to make it a network location and tried accessing it using the appropriate IP address (as was automatically supplied when I plugged it in) from another PC.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. There are some pieces of information missing in your question. 1) What have you tried so far? 2) What OS are you using? 3) What does the wireless network have to do with the question? If you [edit] your question to include this information will help us help you.

Comment: 1) I have tried sharing the USB drive, _tried_ to make it a network location and tried accessing it using the appropriate IP address (as was automatically supplied when I plugged in) from another PC. 2) I'm running Windows 8.1 3) The wireless network was relevant because I'm connected to it and explicitly didn't want to share the USB device on it - only on the _wired_ network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your operating system. However, assuming you are using Windows, you should be able to share your USB drive as a "shared folder" on the network.

You can find more information on sharing folders under Windows 7 here: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-share-folders-in-windows-7-with-the-shared-folder-wizard/3180/#.